# jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 taphold event fired multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I bind a taphold event to td-elements of a table, but when i tap and hold to trigger the event, it is somehow fired multiple times. My example code:

```
$("td").on("taphold", function(){
    alert("taphold fired!");
});
```

If I hold the tap, I'll receive at least 6 alert messages at once.
How can I make the event just fire once while holding?
I tested the code on an Ipad with safari and chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) too:

```
$("td").off("taphold");
$("td").on("taphold", function(){alert("taphold fired!");});
```

You need to make sure you have only one event handler for taphold at one time. Also this triggers many taphold events.

Comment: this works for me. Thanks! We can also chain the 2 lines to make use of the chaining ability of jQuery.

Answer (score 7):

### Intro

**`jQuery Mobile`** works in a different way then classic web applications. Depending on how you managed to bind your events each time you visit mentioned page it will bind events over and over. This is not an error, it is simply how **`jQuery Mobile`** handles its pages.

There are several solutions to your problem. Each solution has a upside and a downside.

### Solution 1

Best solution would be to use **`pageinit`** to bind events. If you take a look at an official documentation you will find out that **`pageinit`** will trigger **ONLY** once, just like document ready, so there's no way events will be bound again. This is best solution because you don't have processing overhead like when removing events with off method.

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AAFH8/

### Solution 2

Remove event before you bind it:

```
$('#index').on('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $(document).off('click', '#test-button').on('click', '#test-button', function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K8YmG/

### Solution 3

Use a **`jQuery Filter`** selector, like this:

```
$('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){
    //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something
});
```

Because event filter is not a part of official **`jQuery`** framework it can be found here:   http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

In a nutshell, if speed is your main concern then **`Solution 3`** is much better then **`Solution 2.`**

### Solution 4

A new one, probably an easiest of them all.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {
            alert('Clicked');
            e.handled = true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Yerv9/

### Final Note

If you want to find out more about page events, how they work and how they can be used to prevent multiple event binding take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog. Or it can also be found **[HERE](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/)**.

Comment: The first solution didn't work for me. I had tried it before asking this question. The second and the fourth work. In the 2nd solution I'd rather use off() and on() instead of die() and live() because the later seems to be deprecated in the new versions of jQuery. I haven't tried the 3rd solution. Anyway thanks for your informative answer.

Comment: @DevX3i You are correct about live, tnx for noticing it, I simply forgot.

Comment: @Floradu88: tnx and +1 for you, I simply forgot about on/off

Comment: Yes, thank you, but together both of our responses offer several alternatives for this.